# AD B2C Custom user journey: Expired token redirect url change

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

As part of our custom user registration flow in AD B2C we send a registration link to the user. If the registratin token expires, we would like to add the users e-mail address to the redirect link.

User clicks on the following link:
 `https://.../<name_of_custom_flow>/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?client_id=1830ce2b-b987-408a-a914-c4f49d807ecc&nonce=defaultNonce&redirect_uri=https://<redirect_link>%2f&state=Y3VsdHVyZT1kZQ&response_mode=query&ui_locales=de&scope=openid&response_type=id_token&base=default&ext=html&id_token_hint=<token>`

User is redirected and the following is appended to the URL:

`.../signin?error=invalid_request&error_description=AADB2C90208%3a+The+provided+id_token_hint+parameter+is+expired.+Please+provide+another+token+and+try+again.%0d%0aCorrelation+ID%3a+c1816fb1-663e-4356-bb24-76b40a97fbae%0d%0aTimestamp%3a+2023-01-05+14%3a24%3a07Z%0d%0a&state=Y3VsdHVyZT1lbi1HQg` 
And we would like to amend the users e-mail into this last URL.

AADB2C90208 error is described here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/error-codes

Can anyone share a hint on how to "catch" this error in the custom user flow scripts?

Tnx

P.S. @rbrayb can you help out?

Tried to go through all of the elements in custom user journey, but none of them are referencing the token validation step.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a [magic link](https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples#user-experience)? You can have any timeout period for that.

The redirectURI is hardcoded in the app. registration. It has to match the parameter in the request. If you add something to it, it will throw an error.

Maybe describe your use case in more detail?